# Create Linux XCB Frameless Window

Tags: linux, x11, xcb

I want to create a frameless window by XCB.
I set the XCB_CW_OVERRIDE_REDIRECT mask to true.
It works, but the keyboard event cannot work.

```
uint32_t value_mask, value_list[32];

window = xcb_generate_id(connection);

value_mask = XCB_CW_BACK_PIXEL | XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
value_list[0] = screen->black_pixel;
value_list[1] =
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_RELEASE |
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS |
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE |
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY |
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_POINTER_MOTION |
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS |
    XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_RELEASE;

if (settings.fullscreen)
{
    width = destWidth = screen->width_in_pixels;
    height = destHeight = screen->height_in_pixels;
}

xcb_create_window(connection,
    XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
    window, screen->root,
    0, 0, width, height, 0,
    XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
    screen->root_visual,
    value_mask, value_list);


const uint32_t values[] ={true,};
xcb_change_window_attributes (connection, window, XCB_CW_OVERRIDE_REDIRECT, values);
```

Do anybody know how to create a frameless window by xcb without key press event bugs?

Comment: If you really just want to get rid of the WM's window decoration, you should use the motif hints to request that. OverrideRedirect does something different (and does a lot more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your override-redirect window to have the input focus, you have to explicitly `xcb_set_input_focus(connection, window);`. Since the input focus can only be given to viewable windows, this has to be done after you mapped your window.

In X11, keyboard events are (basically) send to the window that currently has the input focus. Normally, the input focus is managed by the window manager. Since you are creating an override-redirect window, the window manager does not see your window and cannot focus it. Thus, you have to focus your window yourself. Note that the WM can still give the focus to other windows and thus your window loses focus.

I am not actually sure what the correct/right way to focus your window per ICCCM is. I did not find a relevant section with a quick search for "override-redirect" or "focus".

My gut feeling is that the right way to handle this issue is to not use an override-redirect window.

Comment: In GTK and Qt, context menus, which are override-redirect windows, simply get their input by grabbing keyboard and mouse. Thus if your app happens to hit a breakpoint while its menu is visible, you have a problem... (There are [various ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/494219/27672) to ungrab, but you still need to do something to get out of this.)

Comment: xcb_map_window(connection, window); xcb_set_input_focus(connection,XCB_INPUT_FOCUS_POINTER_ROOT,window,XCB_CURRENT_TIME); Solve this problem. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
xcb_map_window(connection, window); 
xcb_set_input_focus(connection,XCB_INPUT_FOCUS_POINTER_ROOT,window,XCB_CURRENT_TIME);
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Typically when answers are posted, a little more detail surrounding the answer is warranted.  In this case:  How does the posted code do what the questioner wanted?  It's great to have a solution, but it's even better to know how and why it works.   This might be helpful: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)